# WebUSB: device.open() on any device causing "Failed to execute 'open' on 'USBDevice': Access denied"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, usb, webusb

I'm playing with a thermal printer to work with [WebUSB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebUSB_API).

Here is the minimal Glitch demo *(please note this demo may show your connected usb devices)*:

- preview: https://canary-adjoining-garlic.glitch.me
- code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/canary-adjoining-garlic

[image]

I'm able to select the (any) device. But unable to call `device.open()`.

```js
document.getElementById("print-button-usb").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log('clicked');
  navigator.usb.requestDevice({ filters: [] })
    .then(device => {
      console.log('device paired', device);
      console.log(device.vendorId, typeof device.vendorId);
      return device;
    })
    .then(device => device.open()) // Error here <<-------------------------------------!
    .catch(err => console.error("my err", err));
})
```

[image]

**Not only that printer, but I'm unable to open any connected shown devices.** Can someone point out what am I missing here?

Environment details:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1
- Chrome Version 107.0.5304.121

I've been following this guide: https://web.dev/usb

---

**Update** : (Debug informations)
My chrome://device-log says: `Failed to open /dev/bus/usb/001/005: Permission denied (13)`. I tried to cat that node:

```bash
$ cat /dev/bus/usb/001/005                    
@V       �2     �@@%                 
$ pwd
/dev/bus/usb/001
$ ls -l
total 0
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 0 Nov 30 23:13 001
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 1 Nov 30 23:13 002
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 2 Nov 30 23:13 003
crw-rw-r-- 1 root root 189, 3 Nov 30 23:13 004
crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp   189, 4 Dec  1 00:07 005
```

---

In the above image,

- Integrated_Webcam_HD: laptop camera
- KT USB Audio: my headphones connected via usb-c
- CB-GK-16 Firefly: Additional keyboard
- USB Portable Printer: the thermal printer I'm playing with

---

I tried to connect my phone over usb and tried to pair - I was able to pair it.

[image]

In this list, the "Pixel 3" device was the only device I was able to successfully connect. All others are returning the "Access Denied" error.

Comment: Does your user have permission to open the USB device node in /dev/bus/usb?

Comment: It seem it is accessible. I tried to cat it. I've updated the question with a bit more details.

Comment: Check the permissions with `ls -l`. It is probably read-only.

Comment: `crw-rw-r-- 1 root lp   189, 4 Dec  1 00:07 005` - I've updated the debug details.

Comment: Your [assumption](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/serial-terminal/issues/52#:~:text=As%20you%20can%20see%20in%20your%20SO) was right. My user was not in the `lp` group. I added it and logged-out-and-logged-in. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here using FTDI device.
I was able to `get` the device but not I could not `open` it with exactly the same error. I was using windows 10 by the way. Problem was solved by changing the driver from FTDI custom driver to `WinUsb` using [zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/).

*note*:
after doing so, the device could not be used by the previous `.NET` application and it is only accessible by the browser.